# Google Colaboratory: Is there any way to expand the height of the result cell of running a code?

Tags: google-colaboratory

In Google Colaboratory notebook I have a loop that generates a lot of charts...my problem is that it does not display the full output nicely. Instead it shows it inside a cell with a scroll bar. I want to show the full result instead of scrolling up and down...but there doesn't seem to be any setting in Google Colaboratory that allows that. I was wondering if anyone knows if it's possible to change the cell height of the result? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Colab release notes](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/relnotes.ipynb) dated 2024-01-08:

> - Avoid nested scrollbars for large outputs by using
>   `google.colab.output.no_vertical_scroll()`
>   [Example notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/blois/635d82605b163fc8fbb8ae1128c7f388/no_vertical_scroll.ipynb)

And doing what the example notebook says:

> By default outputs are limited to a maximum of 1000px of vertical height, but sometimes you expect large outputs but don't want the annoying nested scrollbars.
>
> To remove this limitation, use:

```py
from google.colab import output
output.no_vertical_scroll()
```

seems to work. It seems you need to do this within the cell for which you want the long output (you cannot just do it in a code cell at the top and have it work "globally").

Answer (score 13):

There's an answer from a dev [here](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/541). Note that the `display(...)` command must be included in every cell you wish to extend the max height of (unless maybe you write some extra javascript). Quote below.

An example in Python:

```
from IPython.display import Javascript
display(Javascript('''google.colab.output.setIframeHeight(0, true, {maxHeight: 5000})'''))

for i in range(200):
  print(i)
```

Comment: Nice! That works, thanks...however, instead of including it in every cell we could just make it a def that gets called in each cell..e.g adjust_height()

Comment: I was using it for a plotting function, so just trowing it in there worked well too!

Comment: Hmm, this did not change anything for me, I still see a scroll bar. I wonder why it worked for some and not others. I have all my code in 1 cell, so it seems like it should work.

Comment: That does not work at all

Comment: What do the different arguments to setIframeHeight do?

Comment: There is now (2024 January) an option to write this as just `from google.colab import output` followed by `output.no_vertical_scroll()`; just posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77826307/4958) below.

Answer (score 11):

I managed to automate this for all cells in the entire Notebook.

Just create a cell with the following code and execute it, all the other cells in the Notebook will be automatically height-adjusted up to 5000px:

```py
# Avoids scroll-in-the-scroll in the entire Notebook
from IPython.display import Javascript
def resize_colab_cell():
  display(Javascript('google.colab.output.setIframeHeight(0, true, {maxHeight: 5000})'))
get_ipython().events.register('pre_run_cell', resize_colab_cell)
```

(It's just a variation of the answers in this thread and a tip from [here](https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/541))

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this at the end of your cell's code:

```
from IPython.display import Javascript
display(Javascript("google.colab.output.resizeIframeToContent()"))
```

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately it's making no difference...I still have the scroll bar in the cell.

Comment: You need to call this at the end of your cell, after all output has been displayed. Then it works. I edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
from IPython.display import HTML
display(HTML('''
<style>
    pre {
        white-space: normal;
    }
</style>
'''))

print('x ' * 200)
```